# Debian PHP file permissions after extract zip archive

Tags: php, permissions, debian, umask

I have a Debian server which I use for php. I have the directory /var/www where my php files are stored.

the whole directory and all files belongs to ftpuser:internetuser. Every file in this directory have the permission 664.

Now there is a .zip archive with the permission 664 too. If I run the php script to extract the archive, all extracted files have the permission 644 and belong to www-data:internetuser.

What is the best way to get my files extracted with the permission 664?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, by adding:

```
umask(0002);
```

before the extract command to my PHP extract script.